# An error appeared : Exception thrown at 0x79ECFC60 (ucrtbased.dll), INST.exe): 0xC0000005: Acsess violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

I was doing a school project of making a program which uses insertion sort to sort the name of cities.
While doing this, This error appeared and I can't find an appropriate answer or a solution to this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_COUNT 10 

void ISAscend(const char* astr_list[], int amax_count) { 
    int i, j;
    const char* temp;
    for (i = 0; i < amax_count - 1; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (strcmp(astr_list[j], astr_list[j + 1]) > 0) {
            temp = astr_list[j];
            astr_list[j] = astr_list[j + 1];
            astr_list[j + 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

void ISDescend(const char* astr_list[], int amax_count) { 
    int i, j;
    const char* temp;
    for (i = 0; i < amax_count - 1; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (strcmp(astr_list[j], astr_list[j + 1]) < 0) {
            temp = astr_list[j];
            astr_list[j] = astr_list[j + 1];
            astr_list[j + 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    const char* str_list[MAX_COUNT] = {
        "seoul", "tokyo", "delhi", "shanghai", "cairo",
        "mumbai", "beijing", "dhaka", "osaka", "karachi"
    }; 

    printf("Insertion Sort (global big cities)");
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("[Ascending order] : ");
    ISAscend(str_list, MAX_COUNT);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++)
        printf("%s - ", str_list[i]);

    printf("\n[Descending order] : ");
    ISDescend(str_list, MAX_COUNT);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++)
        printf("%s - ", str_list[i]);
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm still learning programing, and I'm so confused.
Can anyone give me a not-too-complicated answer for this problem?
This project was by a discrete math professor and he demanded us to search for any necessary information because he didn't teach any of this, and I just learned what pointer is last night through youtube...
As far as I know, this error is because of trying to write in a read only space, and I can't figure out what that means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the value of `j` is in range before doing `strcmp(astr_list[j], astr_list[j + 1])`, or they may be out-of-range and *undefined behavior* due to out-of-range access may be invoked.

It should be like this:

```
        while (j >= 0 && strcmp(astr_list[j], astr_list[j + 1]) > 0) {
```